# Is it bad practice to include external libraries inside web component?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'm just starting playing with web component. I'm so used to using jQuery, and not sure if I can use some of its functionality inside defining my web component custom Element. Is this considered a bad practice? Is only vanilla Javascript allowed inside? What is the pro and con and for what reason? Thanks.

Comment: Are you really asking if it it is a bad idea to have dependencies?  Modern software cannot exist *without* them.

Comment: If you want to use your component in other places then avoid dependencies. I have none in any of mine unless I include them IN each component. If you have a base class that you use for all of your Web Components that can work then then you need to make sure that everyone loads it first. If you are using `import` then that reduces the problem, but the other developers will need to know what libraries they must include to use your component. Tread lightly.

Comment: how do you plan to publish your component? say with webpack you will get all you dependencies [bundled by default](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#externalize-lodash) or you can change the config to avoid bundling dependencies and include them as `peerDependencies` in `package.json` for your component(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessarily a bad practice. Actually it depends on what you intend to do with your Web Component.

If it's for learning purpose, or if it's to design rapid prototypes, it can be a a good idea.

If it's to distribute them, maybe it's a bad habit for the reason developed in [this post about stacking up different framworks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53099841/4600982): for example you could face some incompatibilies between different versions of jQuery: the one you use inside your Custom Element, and the developer use in the page that includes your Custom Element.